# Changing \definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39} statement to a \newcommand statement

Tags: macros, color, definition

I am using Springer journals template (SVJour3). The template says that do not use `\def` but
use `\newcommand{}{}` to make your own definitions.

I had a statement `\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}` which I use in the following context for making an  Orcid icon:

```
\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}
```

I need to change the statement  `\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}` with a `\newcommand` instead of the `\def` statement.  Your suggestions is highly appreciated?

Comment: Use definecolor, that has nothing to do with def.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback @Ulrike. I was just worried it does.

Comment: Actually, `\DeclareRobustCommand` is much more akin to `\def`. That is where you might need to use `\newcommand`.